# Is it possible to hide the soft keyboard in android and still retain focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm programatically focusing a input text element upon clicking a button.

But in android devices it soft keyboard is popping out on focusing the input element.

Is it possible to hide the soft keyboard in android and still retain focus with JavaScript as I'm inputing the data via scanning bar code and not via soft keyboard?

Comment: @cracker I'm talking about html input and JavaScript, not the about the andoid native app code

Comment: @cracker read my question thoroughly, that solution will not retain the focus.